# How do I stretch a div vertically in a td?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a div inside a td. The td has a height. How I can stretch the div vertically - without setting its height explicitely.

```
<td style='height:200px'>
<div>hello<div>
<td>
```

I tried setting the vertical-alignment but there is no "stretch" value.

Comment: You don't have any closing tags. Have you tried `height: 100%;` for the div ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/hnBNk/

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style='height:200px; border: 1px solid red;'>
            <div style="border: 1px solid blue;">hello</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
div { /* This is a sample! Of course a class 'my_div' would make more sense */
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
td div {
   height:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
<td style='height:200px'>
<div style="height:100%">hello<div>
<td>
```

OK, it is explicit definition, but it stretches according to parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`<div style="min-height:100%">`
It will automaticly stretch if the text needs more space (vertically)